# Find and combine elements starting with specific letters in Python Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have a list of words:
Suppose

```
myList =['typical', 'tower', 'temporary', 'system','source','sky']
```

and another:

```
aList = ['t','s']
```

I want to find elements in **myList** that start with elements in **aList** and combine them.

Like:

```
> typical system
> tower source
```

I am able to find elements with `listItem.startswith` but I'm unable to combine them, using **aList** according to the order they are placed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want *all* possible combinations?

Comment: @AnnZen Not all combinations, because it freezes up the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import product

# The data.
words = ['typical', 'tower', 'temporary', 'system', 'source', 'sky']
letters = ['t', 's']

# Organize the words by starting letter.
word_groups = [
    [w for w in words if w.startswith(let)]
    for let in letters
]

# A Cartesian product of all word groups gives every possible phrase.
phrases = list(product(*word_groups))

# Check.
for p in phrases:
    print(p)
```

Output:

```
('typical', 'system')
('typical', 'source')
('typical', 'sky')
('tower', 'system')
('tower', 'source')
('tower', 'sky')
('temporary', 'system')
('temporary', 'source')
('temporary', 'sky')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the list is large like having about 2000+ items, if I try to use the method you shared, it freezes up the system, and terminal returns "killed".

Comment: @HarisIjazWarraich OK, in that case, don't generate every possible phrase (skip the Cartesian product step). Instead just randomly select as many phrases as you need from `word_groups`.